# Google maps, get center is not on the center. Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I have a problem that when i try to get the center of the map it is different from the center of the screen and in different devices there are different distance differences.. How can i get the true center of the map? I need to add a marker in it

Thank you

Part of the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/crosshair"
        android:src="@drawable/crosshair"
        android:onClick="btPontoClick"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java code that get the center:

```
public void btPontoClick(View v){
    LatLng latlng =  mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
    addPonto(latlng);
    okParaVoltar = false;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in a different way.

Now I convert the Position(X,Y) in the screen of a ImageView to LatLng to google maps!

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Target depends on the bearing and rotation of the camera.
The best way is to get the screen point of the "center" of the map and then translate it to a map point by doing:

```
myMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(screenPoint);
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection

Pay attention that:

> Returns the geographic location that corresponds to a screen location.
>   **The screen location is specified in screen pixels (not display pixels) relative to the top left of the map (not the top left of the
>   whole screen).**